# Select statement using handlebars in Ember

Tags: ember.js

/ exams / template.hbs

```
<form>
  <select name="selectvalue" id="selectvalue">
     <option value="one"> One </option>
     <option value="two"> Two </option>
     <option value="three"> Three </option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" {{action "printans"}}> Submit </button>
</form>
```

/ exams / controller.hbs

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
export default Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        printans: function(){
            let val = this.get('selectvalue');
            console.log(val);
        }
    }
});
```

All I need is I want to replace the html code in the `template.hbs` with handlebars, and when the form is submitted, I need to pass the value to the controller.

Comment: Seems like you are missing an action listening to [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) of select element and setting selected value accordingly. Also you want to set the `selected` property of `option` element depending on selected option. `eq` helper of ember-truth-helpers could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
<form>
    {{#power-select
      selected=selectvalue
      options=cities
      onchange=(action "printans")
      as |name|
    }}
      {{name}}

    {{/power-select}}
</form>
```

I'm totally guessing here.
Additional Details would be helpful:
 - what are you trying to do (specifically)
 - where do you get your list of items?

There is this addon, which covers a lot more common behavior: https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select